# Is it possible to run cron based on a condition in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a Jenkins Pipeline that uses cron to trigger, but I only want to use this cron when a new version is available. What is the best way to use conditions in Cron?

```
pipeline {

    agent any
      triggers {
        Cron('''
        0 21 * * * % ${old_version} != ${new_version}
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Pipeline:Initalize') {
            steps { 
                script{
                         xxxxxxxxxx
          }
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

AKAIK You can't do something like that. But you can conditionally skip the Stages with a [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) condition.

```
pipeline {

    agent any
      triggers {
        Cron('''
        0 21 * * * % 
        ''')
    }
    stages {
      when { expression { return ${old_version} != ${new_version} }
        stage('Pipeline:Initalize') {
            steps { 
                script{
                         xxxxxxxxxx
          }
        }
      }
     }
```